# php codes to retrive blobs fom a single row

Tags: php

I am getting to insert images to database tables but unfortunately I am unable to retrieve BLOB data/image at my browser using queries with `where id=$id`. A huge number of machine language type text comes out.

Can anybody provide me complete PHP codes for retrieving BLOB data from a single row of a table of database?

Thanks.

Comment: _“A huge number of machine language type text comes out.”_ – that’s what happens when you forget to tell the browser _how_ he should interpret the data you send him. Send an appropriate `Content-Type` header before outputting the image data.

Answer (score 1):

This should make your 'machine language' show as an image on your webpage.

```
$result = <machineCode from database>;
header("Content-type: image/jpg");
print $result;
```

see: [Convert Blob To Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106470/php-convert-a-blob-into-an-image-file)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, if you store the blob in a variable you can then echo it out as an image.

[How to echo an image with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552457/how-to-echo-an-image-with-php)